# Reading Numbers from a .dat file with numbers arranged columnwise into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-read

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     int block[100];
     int i = 0;

     FILE *fp;

     fp = fopen("blockage.dat","r");

     if (fp != NULL){
     while( !feof(fp) )
     {
         fscanf(fp,"%d",&block[i++]);
     }
     }
     fclose(fp);

     return 0;

}
```

My blockage.dat file looks like this:

```
3.712e+05
4.265e+05
5.345e+05
....
```

The numbers are arranged row wise. So my C program is stuck in the first loop itself.
How do I sort this ? How do I ensure that it goes to the next line ?

Comment: how are the numbers stored in file ? I mean , is it a text or binary file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is `i` declared in your program?

Set i to 0.

```
int i = 0;
```

The file contains floating type data.
So your array should be

```
float block[100];
```

Then do

```
while((fscanf(fp,"%f",&block[i++])) != EOF);
```

Depending on the values which you are reading you declare your array with `double` or `long double` type.

Comment: Thank you Gopi . But If I declared my fscanf to read %d values then  should it not truncate the floating real numbers to the nearest integer ? Why would it not read the file at all ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with arrangement; you are trying to read floats into integer variables.

Comment: The point is this : the numbers which mMATLAB writes into the file is of the form of exponential form even though it is of type int. I didn't know that this would require me to read it in float.

Comment: By telling `fscanf` to read an int (%d), you are telling it to *look* for an int (and it doesn't consider exponential form to be an int).  By telling it to look for a float (%f), it will read the value as such.  If you want to store it in an `int` variable afterward, have at it.